# Why are my downloaded google photos folders so huge using google-takeout?

Tags: google-drive

I created backup of my google-photos using google takeout and downloaded it but its huge. I got three files two 50 GB each and one 33 GB (total 133 GB).

But I use only 14 GB out of my 15 GB google drive limit, most of it is used by google photos in original sizes.

So why is backup so massive? I noticed it has json files too with every image or video but still, it doesn't make sense the archive to be this huge.

Comment: Are you sure you are comparing the same data here? JSON and other text files are unlikely to get you gigabytes of data. Are you sure you store at Original resolution or '[High Quality](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)'?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things that could make your archive that big.

- You have switched at some point to the option to store photos at [High Quality](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) rather than original resolution. High Quality images are quota free
- You have many albums using the same images. Each album has all images in the archive. (I'm not sure if this is the case)
- You have lost some free storage quota e.g. I had 100GB for 24 months once I registered by HTC mobile phone at some stage

Comment: That might explain it. I had combination of high quality images (unlimited) as well as original resolution resolution was about 14 GB so it could mean the rest are the unlimited high quality images?